# Is gnu screen or tmux more stable for keeping running on the server?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I want to keep a screen or tmux session running forever on a Ubuntu server, possibly for running a Clojure web server application so I can tap into the process via REPL at any time. Gnu screen or tmux -- which is less prone to crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to use a `screen` session for bootstrapping Java and Rails application for months, so I tend to consider `screen` stable enough for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to measure since screen is matured and tmux is not but tmux has such a clear codebase that it smoothly went into OpenBSD. Quite often I use both at the same time. ;-)